# How to make 1 html id equal another HTML id?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a calculator and I want it to display 2 sets of the total. So say the calculation was 2 + 2 = 4 I want it to display 4 (the total) twice. However, my javascript is spitting it out through an html id. So how do I make another total?  Basically, how do I make one id equal another id?

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique.  You would either have to use `removeAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` or go about it in another manner.

```
document.getElementById(_id).removeAttribute("id");
document.getElementById(_id).setAttribute("id", _newId);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a class and use getElementsByClassName

or with jquery use `$('.className').val(value)`

OR...

you can simply say `$('#thisID').val($('#thatID').val());`